# WebView does not scroll div in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-webview

I am using a ViewPager that contains WebViews. Horizontal scroll does work for pages that are zoomed in (WebView scrolls to the end, then the ViewPager scrolling logic jumps in) but fails for scrollable divs (like in carousels with scrolling product images at amazon or other online shops). Here the ViewPager starts scrolling its page immediately instead of scrolling the WebView's carousel first.

The ViewPager itself is wrapped in a SwipeRefreshLayout to achieve pull-to-refresh. Vertical scroll does work with the help of its canChildScrollUp()-method. This should not affect the horizontal scroll nonetheless.

The layout looks like this (simplified):

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            // Bunch of WebViews

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

The WebViews are created programmatically in the instantiateItem()-method of the ViewPager's PagerAdapter.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    WebView webView = new WebView(context);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
    container.addView(webView);
    return webView;
}
```

I am using the support library 25.1.1 and the Android System WebView 56.0.2924.87.

Thanks in advance and best regards!

TL;DR: I need a ViewPager that does not scroll until the underlying HTML divs of a WebView cannot be scrolled furthermore.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this bug? I have the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently I was not able to resolve this bug, so I deactivated the horizontal scroll for my ViewPager via its canScroll() method. Now the pages can only be changed via a surrounding TabLayout, but the scrolling inside my WebViews does work as expected.

Maybe there is a way to toggle the result of canScroll() by identifying the HTML of the WebView, but I was not able to due to its asynchronous nature.

Comment: I see. Thanks anyway for your reply!